# 链接, 连接, 连结, 联接, 联结 - lianjie - is it a joke and if not, what's the difference?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, characters, word

Amongst 链接, 连接, 连结, 联接, 联结 - which one is the most correct to use in which situation? Is one more formal than others? Maybe the meanings are different? Please, write as much as possible about differences between these words which mean "link, connect".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a story.

There is a Japanese cellphone game called “Princess Connect! Re:Dive” (プリンセスコネクト! Re:Dive). Before it was officially released in China, people are discussing which is the correct translation of the name, because in the context all these words have almost the same meaning "connected". But when it is released the official name 公主连结 is the least discussed, as if the company is trying to avoid people's expectation. Any way, folks are calling it 公主焊接(princess weld) now.

Beyond the story:

break the words:

- 链: originally means a chain, but now more refer to a internet link
- 连: physical connection (from distance)
- 联: abstract connection
- 接: connect by touching
- 结: knot

The words:

- 链接: link to, internet related word
- 连接: connect, more physically, but can infer abstract connect
- 连结: physically tie the knot, metaphor for spiritual connection.
- 联接: abstract connection between people
- 联结: a combination of 联接 and 连结, spiritually tie the knot, same as spiritual connection.

Usage:

- 链接 is almost always used under internet context
- 连接 can be physical or abstract, but usually not between people
- 连结, 联接 and 联结 are usually abstract, where 连结 and 联结 are mostly for people relationships.

In Chinese, verbs can be used as nouns. Here is the case.

Comment: 公主焊接 LMAO some serious electric action over there...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, these words are also confusing most Chinese nowadays.

We use '连接' the most in general writing to instead the others just for convenience, though it's wrong, yet still, everyone can get it.

链：chain

连：connect, link

联：ally,  liaison

---

Formal use:

1. 链接：Just a noun, not a verb. It refers to a link or hyperlink on the Internet

   - 同时打开两个链接：Open two links simultaneously.
   - 生成一个短网址链接：Genrate a short URL.
   - 点击该链接获得优惠券：Click the link to get the coupon.

---

2. 联接 = 连接：Means connect to something or a connection.

   - 连接号(-)：a punctuation for connecting
   - 连接你我：Connect each other.
   - 网络连接：The connection to the internet/network.
   - 网络的连接：The connection of the internet/network.
   - 连接网络：Connect to the internet/network.
   - 我连接掉线了：I got disconnected/ I lost the connection(to the server).
   - 这两个车厢的连接很脆弱：The coupling of these two carriages is fragile.

In Chinese, we seldom use '联接'.
Similarly, English speakers often use  'connection' rather than 'connexion', right? Yet they have the same meaning.

---

3. 联结 = 连结 ：Through something to combine something together .

   - 画一条直线把这两点联结起来：Draw a straight line to connect these two dots.
   - 此地是联结南北的交通要道：This region is a major transit hub for traffic to connect the South and the North.

---

In fact, it's unnecessary to figure out what are these words stand for precisely. Just remember these three words should be enough.

- 连接：verb, noun, connect multiple things, a connection or linkage of multiple things
- 链接：noun, a link on Internet
- 连结：verb, combine multiple things together via something

Answer (score 0):

Link:
链接
Liànjiē

Connect:
连接, 连结, 联接, 联结

liánjiē, liánjié, liánjiē, liánjié

链：chain

连：in succession

联：ally, unite

接: receive

结: comprise